# Why do some people take a photo, then a screenshot of the photo and only then share it?

Tags: iphone, photos, screen-capture

I see screenshots of pictures in the Photos app all the time. For example:
[image]

So someone took a picture, then went to Photos app, took a screenshot of it, then went to Photos app again and only then shared it. Seems like two steps too many to share a pic.

And I see it everywhere: on Craigslist, at my friends houses printed out on the walls, it's ridiculous.

The only explanation I can think of would be a cheap hack to save some space on disk and/or traffic due to the fact that a screenshot is smaller than the original image. But the kinds of places you normally see this suggest that it's probably some form of ignorance. It's just that usually ignorance is a shortcut. But here we witness a detour.

Comment: Most often when I see the screenshot of a picture thing, the first app isn't the photos app.  It's some other communications type app.  My assumption is the person doesn't know how to save pics in that app, so they screenshot it to reshare.

Comment: Ah, you mean someone got it on WhatsApp, but doesn't know where the Save button is and how to get to the picture after it's saved? That's a good hypothesis. Though, it seems to me if a person knows what a screenshot is and how to take it, they would be able to figure out the Save button thing. But who knows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really has nothing to do with apple or even any other system but just asks for speculation about why people do things a certain way with their computer.  Belongs is some kind of chat group and not a tech assist forum.

Answer (score 5):

It's likely this question will be closed because it's primarily opinion-based.

However, one potential reason why some people may choose to take a screenshot of a photo before sharing it is due to privacy concerns.

For example, if I take a photo with my iPhone 6s and view the EXIF data, it will show that the photo was taken with an iPhone 6s, which camera was used (front or back), the exposure, the Date and Time, the Location (an actual address where possible), etc etc. In fact, there's over 50 fields of data if viewing the full record. However, if I take a screenshot of that exact same photo, and view the EXIF data of that, I will see almost no information beyond the fact it's a screenshot, the resolution, file size, and a *guess* of when the screenshot was taken.

You can prove this to yourself by using an online EXIF viewer to upload a photo. There are many of them around, but for example you could try http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi and upload a photo from your phone to view its data. Then take a screenshot of that same photo and upload that instead.

In summary, for some users it probably isn't just *a cheap hack to save some space on disk and/or traffic due to the fact that a screenshot is smaller than the original image.*

Comment: That's a good explanation and could be a plausible one for posting on Craigslist case. However, even though there's a lot of talk about privacy, I doubt that more than a tiny fraction of people actually know about EXIF and care about stripping it.

Comment: It's definitely not an easy thing to quantify, hence why I said this may be the case for _some_ users. There is a lot of talk about privacy and even my teenage daughters know about the fact there is metadata attached to any digital photo they take (not sure how they knew - perhaps taught at school), so the concern is probably more prevalent than we realise. I also regularly see laptops where the camera has tape over it, so privacy is becoming a much greater concern for people generally. But of course, the example you provide about photos printed out on walls would imply a level of ignorance.